# Azure DevOps Code Review (Pull Request) incorrectly showing differences from multiple updates - any fix?

Tags: azure-devops

Within a pull-request, Azure DevOps helpfully lets you select which "update(s)" (i.e. code pushes) within the pull-request you'd like to review, but this feature no longer works properly.

For example, if I already reviewed a pull-request at update 3, and a developer has just pushed update 4, I can select to see only the changes between update 3 and update 4 (rather than all changes, which would show me lots of updates that I've already reviewed).

I'm recently finding that this feature doesn't work properly, and that when I select to view only the most recent "update" in a pull request (i.e. view the differences between the most recent two code pushes), DevOps code review shows me all differences between the base (original) push and the selected update.

Is there anything I can try to fix this, or is it simply a bug with Azure DevOps? I've tried using multiple machines with differing browsers over a period of several weeks, but the issue keeps recurring.

Answer (score 0):

I also raised this issue over on Visual Studio's Developer Community and it was picked up, analysed and fixed by the team there. We've not had any further issues since, so I presume a bug was introduced, but has now been sorted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).